# stop error reporting in php for linux command

Tags: php, linux, error-handling

I want to stop error of linux command which is use with php. How Can I stop this error?

I have used **error_reporting(0);**

But fail to stop error.

My code is this

```
`sudo touch $patch_detail_file`;
`sudo chmod 0777 -R $patch_detail_file`;
```

My Apache2 error log is like this

```
chmod: cannot access 'Description/Tiguin-LBP-NetworkPrinter.description': No such file or directory
sh: 1: cannot create Description/Tiguin-LBP-NetworkPrinter.description: Directory nonexistent
touch: cannot touch '18092014/Description/Tiguin-Brother-MFCJ200.description': No such file or directory
```

Comment: And because error goes high my server load average is increased.

Comment: Please note that chmod 777 is rarely needed and not a good idea, because you basically throw all security of the Linux file system out of the window. 775 should be sufficient for most cases.

Answer (score 0):

With error_reporting you just disable php displaying errors on screen or in the **PHP** error log. What you see are error messages logged by the **Apache** web server. It is not possible to disable these at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to suppress the error output, you can redirect it to `/dev/null`:

```
`sudo touch $patch_detail_file 2>/dev/null`;
`sudo chmod 0777 -R $patch_detail_file 2>/dev/null`;
```